Search suggestion using Elastic search
i add elastic search popular suggestion of that searched keyword
     var suggest = new ElasticAutoSearchProductRequest.Suggest
         {
             mySuggester = new ElasticAutoSearchProductRequest.Suggest.MySuggester
             {
                 text = keyword,
                 term = new ElasticAutoSearchProductRequest.Suggest.Term
                 {
                     field = "suggest_field",
                     suggest_mode = "popular"
                 }
             }
         };


also get suggestions of that keyword but not getting
what should i add in suggest_field???
